# How to specify single endpoint to be metered in micrometer in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I would like to limit metrics

`http.server.requests.seconds` to a single method and uri.

Currently, I can see that all URIs are being metered (eg. `/actuator/health`)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I registered `MeterRegistryCustomizer` bean and called `meterFilter`:

```kotlin
...
.meterFilter(MeterFilter.deny { id ->
            val uri = id.getTag("uri")
            uri != null && uri.startsWith("/actuator")
        })
```